# Tengo una duda sobre el tipo de palabras que detecta los parametros

Tags: javascript

me di cuenta de algo interesante para mi que soy nuevo y es que estaba haciendo una funcion en javascript para llamarla y usarla con el evento `onclick`, entonces al poner el evento en el codigo HTML y poner `onclick="function("mibg")"` un parametro con un nombre cualquiera. el codigo me da un error de que el parametro `mibg` no existe, pero si en cambio le doy alguna otra palabra como `this`, si funciona.

Entonces quisiera saber si solo detecta alguna palabra como parametros los eventos o por que sucede esto?. muchas gracias

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Calculadora Personal </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/calculadora_personal.css">
    </head>
<body id="todo">
    <div>
    <center>
    <table border="0" width="250px" height="60" id="operaciones">
     <tr>
       <td height="50px" colspan="4"><label for="operador"></label>
       <input type="text" name="operador" id="pantalla" value=""></td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="1" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="ingresa_dato(this)"></td>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="2" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="ingresa_dato(this)"></td>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="3" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="ingresa_dato(this)"></td>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="+" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="operaciones(this)"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="4" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="ingresa_dato(this)"></td>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="5" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="ingresa_dato(this)"></td>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="6" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="ingresa_dato(this)"></td>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="-" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="operaciones(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="7" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="ingresa_dato(this)"></td>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="8" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="ingresa_dato(this)"></td>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="9" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="ingresa_dato(this)"></td>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="*" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="operaciones(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="clr" name="boton" class="boton" onclick=""></td>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="0" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="ingresa_dato(this)"></td>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="=" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="resultado('res')"></td>
        <td class="cuadros"><input type="button" value="/" name="boton" class="boton" onclick="operaciones(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </center>
        </div>
    <script src="js/Calculadora_personal.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

    var valor = document.getElementById("pantalla");

function ingresa_dato(obj){

    valor.value += obj.value;
    console.log(obj.value);
}

function operaciones(ope) {

    var operacion = 

    valor.value += ope.value;

    console.log(valor.value);

}

function resultado(resultado){



}
```

Comment: añade por favor tu código, de otra manera no tenemos como ayudar

Comment: Hola, intenta realizar esto: onclick = 'nombredelafuncion("mibg")'; Al poner this, estas haciendo referencia al objeto html. Además se tienen que utilizar dos tipos de comillas diferentes, es decir comillas simples o comillas dobles en estos casos. Saludos.

Comment: si es que al poner ejemplo onclick="operaciones(mibg)" me dice que mibg no esta definida. en cambio this, no tiene problema, yo pense que alli se le podia colocar cualquier nombre

Comment: El migb debe ir entre comillas simples, intenta onclick="operaciones('mibg')" sí no entrecomillas el mibg se interpreta como una referencia.

Comment: lo intente pero cuando lo quiero ejecutar me sale que es indefinido

Comment: @maxwellsalazar te mejoré la explicación del por que de las comillas simples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo para que comprendas mejor como debes manejar el uso de la función que indicas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="saludos('alfredo')">Hola</button>
<script>
    function saludos(name){
      alert(name);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Las comillas simples son necesarias por que asi el interprete sabe que
>   va a esperar por ejemplo un valor excpresado en formato de cadena de
>   texto
>
> Por el contrario si el valor es numérico o un objeto del navegador no
>   debe ir entre comillas, te invito a que en mi ejemplo sistituyas
>   "alfredo" por 2 así son comillas e igual funcionará

---

> Ahora para que dicho parámetro funcione y sea leido lo tienes que
>   asignar a una variable en el cuerpo de la función, en mi ejemplo le
>   puse name, al hacer eso el interprete sabe que debe esperar un valor
>   dinámico que al momento de hacer un click name va a intercambiarse por
>   una cadena de texto que ahora dice "alfredo"

**EJEMPLO CON UN VALOR NUMÉRICO**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="saludos(2)">Hola</button>
<script>
    function saludos(numero){
      alert(numero);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EJEMPLO CON EL OBJETO WINDOW**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="saludos(window)">Hola</button>
<script>
    function saludos(element){
      alert(element);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si lo entendi mejor. lo probe en un codigo aparte y si me funciono pero en mi codigo original no me funciona no se por que

Comment: Estoy intentando hacer una calculador y pues hice botones para que se guardaran en un input tipo texto los numeros para que los mostrara en pantalla. supongo que por que tienen esa variante algo cambia

Comment: trata de continuar tu código con los comentarios que te hice en mi respuesta @maxwellsalazar o en otro caso puedes postear tu código y ayudarte

Comment: vale ya lo publico

Comment: mmm lo intente publicar pero al parecer no me salia completo. jaja soy nuevo aqui y no se muy bien aun como se maneja del todo

Comment: @maxwellsalazar dale en editar a tu pregunta y pega el código ahi una vez hecho eso selecciona todo el código y dale click en el ícono de `{}` para que kle de formato y se vea completo

Comment: listo ya lo edite